# placing the django login form onto a bootstrap modal

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-urls

I am still learning django and I have run into an issue I do not know how to solve.

I have a django login form that is working. The user clicks on the login link on the landing page and the user is taken to the login page, where the user can login.

I am now trying to make the login form on a bootstrap modal, so that when the user clicks on the login link from the landing page (or the About Us, T&C, Privacy, FAQ's pages) the modal is displayed with the login form (rather than sending the user to a seperate page) and the user logs in.

I have created the modal and I have dropped the login form on to the modal.

The issue that I have is that the username and password fields do not appear on the modal form when I am on the landing page. The form header and buttons do, but the username and password input fields do not.

**Can someone point out what I am missing?**

I suspect that my error is somehow related to the login urls.py file, but I cannot be sure (I may also be on the wrong track by thinking the issue is to do with the users urls.py file).

I have worked through my code and read the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/) but cannot figure out what I have done wrong.

Here is my form login code that I cut and pasted to the modal on my landing page:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% load l10n %}
{% load humanize %}
{% load form_fields %}
....
<form id="login_form" class="reg-page" method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
    {% if form.errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger alignCenter">
            <strong>
                {% trans "Incorrect username or password." %}
                <br />
                {% trans "Please try again." %}
            </strong>
        </div>
        <br />
    {% elif form.account_disabled_error %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger alignCenter">
            <strong>
                {% trans "Account Disabled." %}
                <br />
                {% trans "Contact Administrator." %}
            </strong>
        </div>
        <br />
    {% endif %}
    <div class="login-input">
        {% form_field form.username %}
    </div>
    <div class="login-input">
        {% form_field form.password %}
    </div>
    <div class="alignCenter">
        <input type="submit" class="btn-u btn-u-blue" value="{% trans 'Log In' %}" />
        <span class="hidden-xs">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="visible-xs"><br /></span>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" onClick="login_form.reset();resetLoginForm();" value="{% trans 'Reset' %}" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="{% trans 'Cancel' %}" data-dismiss="modal" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is mu users urls.py file code (I am not sure if I need to display this - just taking a guess):

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from .forms import CustomAuthenticationForm
from globalx.core import LANGUAGES

urlpatterns = patterns(

    'django.contrib.auth.views',

    url(r'^login/$', 'login', {'template_name': 'users/login.html', 'authentication_form': CustomAuthenticationForm, 'extra_context': {'languages': LANGUAGES, }, }, name='login'),

    url(r'^logout/$', 'logout', {'template_name': 'users/logout.html', 'extra_context': {'languages': LANGUAGES, }, }, name='logout'),

    url(r'^change_password/$', 'password_change', {'template_name': 'users/change_password.html'}, name='change_password'),

    url(r'^reset_password/$', 'password_reset', {'template_name': 'users/reset_password.html', 'email_template_name': 'users/reset_password_email.txt', 'subject_template_name': 'users/reset_password_subject.txt', 'extra_context': {'languages': LANGUAGES, }, }, name='reset_password'),

    url(r'^reset_password_done/$', 'password_reset_done', {'template_name': 'users/reset_password_done.html', 'extra_context': {'languages': LANGUAGES, }, }, name='password_reset_done'),

    url(r'^reset_password_confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$', 'password_reset_confirm', {'template_name': 'users/reset_password_confirm.html', 'extra_context': {'languages': LANGUAGES, }, }, name='password_reset_confirm'),

    url(r'^reset_password_complete/$', 'password_reset_complete', {'template_name': 'users/reset_password_complete.html', 'extra_context': {'languages': LANGUAGES, }, }, name='reset_password_complete'),

)

urlpatterns += patterns('globalx.users.views', url(r'^obtain_username/$', 'obtain_username', name="obtain_username"), )
```

Comment: what does your {% load form_fields %} do? and... Why are you using {% form_field form.username %} instead of {{ form.username }}?

Comment: webzy, {% load form_fields %} & {% form_field form.username %} is a template to format the form fields - textbox, select list, text area etc.

Comment: This is probably easier. Have a look at widget tweaks there.

Comment: Well, in that case you should be calling {% form_fields form.username %} not {% form_field form.username %} no?

Comment: webzy, that was my typing error - should be (and is) {% form_field form.username %}